# sql calculating average occupancy of reservation during the term

Tags: mysql, sql

need help on arithmetic calculation of queries

I want to calculate average occupancy of the reservation during particular term. What i am trying is (Total family counts)/ (Total reservation counts) and column should be grouped

First query gives me below

```
Total Family
2
3
1
1
1
3
```

and second gives me 3, but complete query still gives me the same result as first query, even if I replaced second query as '3'

```
Total Family
2
3
1
1
1
3
```

Trying this query:

```
SELECT COUNT( familymember.id ) AS 'Total Family'
FROM familymember,
  reservation
WHERE familymember.fid = reservation.patientId
GROUP BY reservation.patientId/
  (SELECT COUNT( reservation.id )
  FROM reservation
  WHERE reservation.checkout <> '0000-00-00'
  AND reservation.checkin BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30'
  )
```

Testing this query

```
SELECT COUNT( familymember.id ) AS 'Total Family'
FROM familymember,
  reservation
WHERE familymember.fid = reservation.patientId
GROUP BY reservation.patientId /3
```

I really appreciate if you help on this.

Thanks

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL database

Comment: Your group by clause doesn't make sense. Say you have patientIds 3, 6 and 9. So you would get three records. If you divide by 3, you just rename your groups 3/3=1, 6/3=2, 9/3=2. Still three groups. So what do you actually want to group by? What does average occupancy mean? Average occupancy per day?

Comment: can you provide you DDL query for table?